# Image1.ImageUrl = .. does not change the picture on the WEB page

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I work on WEB app on C# VS 2010.
I have WEB form with the button and Image control.
I draw my own image in bitmap.

```
        bitmap.Save(Server.MapPath("pic1.jpg"), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        Image1.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("pic1.jpg");
```

The problem is that the above code does not change the picture in "Image1"

I also tryed as follows:
           bitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream,ImageFormat.Jpeg);
It works. I see my image.
But I don't see any other controls on the WEB page:
no my buttons, labels, etc.
Only the image on the page.

Perhaps I have to bind my own image in bitmap to Image1 somehow different?

Thanks.

Comment: What _does_ happen with this code?  Is the file being saved?  When does this code execute in relation to the page output?  Maybe you're setting `Image1.ImageUrl` after it's already been rendered to the browser?  We need more context about this code.  (Also, what you also tried resulted in expected behavior.  If you output _only_ an image to the browser than that's all the browser will see.)

Answer (score 2):

The `Server.MapPath` returns a **file name**. On the other hand, `Image.ImageUrl` expects a valid **url**.

How do you expect a file name will magically act as an url?

You'd rather want something like

```
Image1.ImageUrl = this.ResolveUrl( "pic1.jpg" );
```

or something similar which resolves paths to navigable uris.

Comment: But how about my second question? Why using bitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream,ImageFormat.Jpeg); I see only this image on the page. No other my  controls on the page (button, labels, etc.)

Comment: Http/html does not work like this - you just **can't** have an image and html in the same response stream!